# Why receiving data from server has a segmentation fault error (No error in sending)?

Tags: c++, regex, sockets, client-server

This error has destroyed my day. This is my second client server program. Server is iterative type.
 The functionality is 
1.server is running all the time. 

2.Client send a file name to server.
3.Server opens the file and process on its data and send information back to client.

 But in the point that client receive data it produce a segmentation error. Even it can read inside the packet, but only "filename".
In fact server is opening a file and open linux dictionary file. It searches for any spelling problem etc. Finally it has line number, word and suggested word.
I have checked inside the list in server side and list has no error.
 here is an abstract of my code. I appreciate if anyone can find the bug. I copy paste all code except processing on the file. Apologist in advance for long code.

**Client side:**

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include "wrappers.h"

struct SType{
  int Num;
  char Word[20];
  char sugg[20];
};


struct DataPktType
{
    list<SType> MyList;
    char filename[MAX_SIZE], message[MAX_SIZE];
    int numslaves;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int Sockfd;
    sockaddr_in ServAddr;
    char ServHost[] = "localhost";
    hostent *HostPtr;
    int Port = SERV_TCP_PORT;
    DataPktType DataPkt;
    DataPktType recDataPkt;
    string filename, tempstr;

    if (argc == 5){
        strcpy(ServHost, argv[1]);
        Port = atoi(argv[2]);
        filename = string(argv[3]);
        cout<<"filename= "<<filename<<endl;
        DataPkt.numslaves = atoi(argv[4]);
    } else{
        cout << "Usage: \"client <server address> <port> <textfile> <numThreads>\".\n" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    // Get the address of the host
    HostPtr = Gethostbyname(ServHost);

    if(HostPtr->h_addrtype !=  AF_INET)
    {
        perror("Unknown address type!");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset((char *) &ServAddr, 0, sizeof(ServAddr));
    ServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = ((in_addr*)HostPtr->h_addr_list[0])->s_addr;
    ServAddr.sin_port = htons(Port);

    // Open a TCP socket
    Sockfd = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // Connect to the server
    Connect(Sockfd, (sockaddr*)&ServAddr, sizeof(ServAddr));

    strcpy(DataPkt.filename, argv[3]);
    DataPkt.numslaves = 6;

    // Write and read a message to/from the server 
    write(Sockfd, (char*)&DataPkt, sizeof(DataPktType));
    read(Sockfd, (char*)&recDataPkt, sizeof(DataPktType));
    cout<<"here"<<endl;
    cout << setw(30) << left << "Filename:" << setw(20) << right << DataPkt.filename << endl;
    list<SType> MyList2;
    MyList2 = DataPkt.MyList;
    cout<<"size= "<<MyList2.size()<<endl;

    for (list<SType>::iterator it=MyList2.begin(); it!=MyList2.end(); it++)
        cout << ' ' << it->Num << ' ' << it->Word << endl;

    cout << "Finished\n";
    close(Sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

**Server side:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream.h>
#include <list>
#include <iomanip>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "wrappers.h"
#include<cstdlib>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include <algorithm>

#define BUFSIZE 10
#define gNumThreads 6
using namespace std;


struct SType{
  int Num;
  char Word[20];
  char sugg[20];
};

struct DataPktType
{
    list<SType> MyList;
    char filename[MAX_SIZE], message[MAX_SIZE];
    int numslaves;
};



int main(int argc, char **argv){

    int Sockfd, NewSockfd, ClntLen, Port = SERV_TCP_PORT;
    sockaddr_in ClntAddr, ServAddr;
    DataPktType DataPkt;


    if (argc == 2){
        Port = atoi(argv[1]);
    }

    // Open a TCP socket (an Internet stream socket)
    Sockfd = Socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // socket() wrapper fn

    // Setup server for development
    setsockopt(Sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof optval);

    // Bind the local address, so that the client can send to server
    memset((char*)&ServAddr, 0, sizeof(ServAddr));
    ServAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    ServAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    ServAddr.sin_port = htons(Port);

    Bind(Sockfd, (sockaddr*) &ServAddr, sizeof(ServAddr));

    // Listen to the socket
    Listen(Sockfd, 5);

    for(;;)
    {
        // Wait for a connection from a client; this is an iterative server
        ClntLen = sizeof(ClntAddr);
        NewSockfd = Accept(Sockfd, (sockaddr*)&ClntAddr, &ClntLen);

        if(NewSockfd < 0)
        {
            perror("Can't bind to local address!");
        }

        // Read a message from the client
        read(NewSockfd, (char*)&DataPkt, sizeof(DataPktType));
        string line;
        ifstream myfile (DataPkt.filename);

        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            --Here is some operation I deleted to make file shorter ---

                    if(!found)
                    {
                        /* Add suggestion to the list */
                        SType S;
                        S.Num = lineNo;
                        strcpy(S.Word, result);
                        strcpy(S.sugg, sugg);
                        MyList2.push_back(S);
                        cout<<lineNo<<"       "<<result<<"         "<<sugg<<endl;
                        cout<<"Not found in dictionary"<<endl;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout<<"found: "<<result<<" in dictionary"<<endl;
                    }
                }
            }

            myfile.close();
            cout<<"List before write"<<endl;

            for (list<SType>::iterator it=MyList2.begin(); it!=MyList2.end(); it++)
                cout << ' ' << it->Num << ' ' << it->Word << endl;

            /*Send suggestion back to the client*/
            DataPktType retPack;

            retPack.MyList = MyList2;
            //DataPkt.filename
            strcpy(retPack.filename,"behzad");

            write(NewSockfd, (char*)&retPack, sizeof(DataPktType));
        }
        else {cout << "Unable to open file"; exit(1);}

    }
    close(NewSockfd);

    /* exit the program */
    return(0);
}
```

**output:**

**serverside:**

```
1       bernard         behead
Not found in dictionary
List before write
lineNo: 1 word: behzad sugg:  behead
```

**clientside:**

```
$ ./client localhost 19431 carol.txt 6
filename= carol.txt
Finished
Segmentation Fault
```

Comment: Use a debugger to find the line here it crashes.

Comment: it crash on client side: read(Sockfd, (char*)&recDataPkt, sizeof(DataPktType)); Exactly when it reads data from server

Comment: Don't you think that DataPktType should be serialized into bytes before sending and deserialized after receiving? To try your code try to send and receive simple array of bytes and check if it crashes.

Comment: How can I serialize the list? any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing any kind of serialization over your data before send or receive.

`write(Sockfd, (char*)&DataPkt, sizeof(DataPktType));
read(Sockfd, (char*)&recDataPkt, sizeof(DataPktType));`

That part is completely wrong, you have a `std::list` into your struct, you need first to process that data before send it.

Comment: How can I serialize the list? any suggestion? The size of the list is variable each time!

Comment: And also when I send data from client to server it works without serialization!